# Recursive function with unknown depth of values. Return all values (undefined depth)

Tags: php, recursion, depth

I have a question about a recursive PHP function.
I have an array of ID’s and a function, returning an array of „child id’s“ for the given id.

```
public function getChildId($id) {
    …
    //do some stuff in db
    …
    return childids;
}
```

One childid can have childids, too!
Now, I want to have an recursive function, collecting all the childids.

I have an array with ids like this:

```
$myIds = array("1111“,"2222“,"3333“,“4444“,…);
```

and a funktion:

```
function getAll($myIds) {

}
```

What I want: I want an array, containing all the id’s (including an unknown level of childids) on the same level of my array. As long as the getChildId($id)-function is returning ID’s…

I started with my function like this:

```
function getAll($myIds) {
    $allIds = $myIds;
    foreach($myIds as $mId) {
        $childids = getChildId($mId);

        foreach($childids as $sId) {
            array_push($allIds, $sId);

            //here is my problem.
            //what do I have to do, to make this function rekursive to
            //search for all the childids? 

        }       
    }
    return $allIds;

}
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked. Can you help me?

Comment: in your current example, `$myIds` is a simple flat array, maybe you could add a proper sample

Comment: Can you put up a better example of your array on which this function has to run? The current one is just a simple one dimensional array with no depth.

Comment: $myIds is my array with the given "root"-Ids. From these Ids, I want to search all the child Id's (my function getChildId()) looks in a table in my database for a dataset having the given Id as primary key, so it is a relation to the root id. In my database one "id" can have many child id's and one child id, can have many child ids, too (and so on))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code should do the trick

```
function getAll($myIds) {
    $allIds = Array();
    foreach($myIds as $mId) {
        array_push($allIds, $mId);
        $subids = getSubId($mId);

        foreach($subids as $sId) {
            $nestedIds = getAll($sId);
            $allIds = array_merge($allIds, $nestedIds);
        }       
    }
    return $allIds;
}
```

Comment: You should add checks to see if it's still an array, otherwise it's going to produce errors.

Comment: where is getSubId() defined?

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution helped me a lot! @halabuda: I changed getSubId to getChildId for a better understanding of my problem.

Comment: @halabuda sorry, i renamed getChildIds to getSubIds. Hadn't had my morning caffeine yet

Comment: @BenFortune Yeah, this is a bit sketchy in that regard, but I was trying to keep close to the question to make it easier to understand. Ideally I would rearrange this so that getSubId is the recursive function, and require that it always be fed 1 ID

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a flat array as in your example, you simply need to call a function that checks each array element to determine if its an array. If it is, the function calls it itself, if not the array element is appended to a result array. Here's an example:

```
$foo = array(1,2,3,
  array(4,5,
    array(6,7,
      array(8,9,10)
    )
  ),
  11,12
);

$bar = array();
recurse($foo,$bar);

function recurse($a,&$bar){
  foreach($a as $e){
    if(is_array($e)){
      recurse($e,$bar);
    }else{
      $bar[] = $e;
    }
  }
}

var_dump($bar);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/gPZKYp8A)

Comment: You need to read the example more carefully. He is not storing all the sub IDs in nested arrays. Instead he has a function to lookup from a DB